# Implementing color themes for my app

Tags: windows-phone-8, themes

I'm developing a WP8 app, and I'm wondering what's the correct way to implement color themes for my app.

Currently, I'm changing the phone's theme resources described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), however I'm wondering, whether that has any side-effects I should know of?

For instance: if I change the color of `PhoneBackgroundBrush`, will that mean that I'll change the bg color of every app and the phone itself? Or, will the change be only current-app-wide?

I change theme resources like so:

```
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code that you used

```
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;
```

Will change the default color of the pages and controls of your app. Not any other app .

These settings get applied to the Application when it is activated. So every app by default has a PhoneBackgroundBrush which is the default theme for the Phone.

But if your app contains Multiple pages with different color then it is always favorable to go by individual Grid

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Red"></Grid>
```

Along with providing

```
App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White
```

For a common application background color :)

All the Properties mentioned in [Themes for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

are meant for a particular application. And you can select any of the following for a global application background color/theme from them.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the consequences if a single instance of these were shared across applications, you could do some real damage with something like that...

You're only changing the resource for the current app.  You're sandboxed and safe